# Flutter Snapshot is null but response from api is not

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fill a ListView with user information, which gets fetched from an api. My snapShot.data is always false but when i log my api response it displays this :

```
{"id":"008","IndexNo":"00000","Name":"JOHN DOE  OCHIENG","IdNumber":"000000","PassportNumber":"","BirthCertNo":"","registration":[{"reg_no":"0000","cadre":"KEN","cadre_text":"KENYA ENROLLED NURSE"},{"reg_no":"0000","cadre":"KEM","cadre_text":"KENYA ENROLLED MIDWIFE"},{"reg_no":"0000","cadre":"KECHN (PB)","cadre_text":"KENYA ENROLLED  COMMUNITY HEALTH NURSE [PB]"}]}
```

This is, how I try to contruct the list view :

```
class UserProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserProfileScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserProfileScreenState createState() => _UserProfileScreenState();
}

class _UserProfileScreenState extends State<UserProfileScreen> {
  //a variable of type future to hold the array of posts returned
  Future<List<User>> _user;
  //variable for holding search data
  String searchString = "";
  //controller to feed into the search string
  final TextEditingController editingController = new TextEditingController();

  //overided the initState method to allow the getPosts method to be run onCreate
  void initState() {
    _user = getUser();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      appBar: AyaAppBar(),
      body: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
              onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overScroll) {
                overScroll.disallowGlow();
                return true;
              },
              //future builder of type <List<User>> to asynchronously list all the posts
              child: new FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
                  future: _user,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData == null) {
                      return Text('No data available');
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    } else {
                      List<User> myUser = snapshot.data;
                      var x = snapshot.hasData;
                      print("here $myUser");
                      return new ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: myUser.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            //TO-DO: add a search widget to allow searches of the various posts
                            return myUser[index].indexNo.contains(searchString)
                                ? Card(
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        ListTile(
                                          enabled: true,
                                          onTap: () {},
                                          title: Text(
                                              myUser[index].name.toString()),
                                          subtitle: Text(myUser[index]
                                              .idNumber
                                              .toString()),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : Container();
                          });
                    }
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }))),
    );
  }
}

//function that returns a list of posts
Future<List<User>> getUser() async {
  var url = Uri.parse('https://xx-api.xxxxxxx.co.ke/api/auth/user');
  var jwt = Globals.token;

  //todo add a try and catch on this http get request, also check internet connection
  var response = await http
      .get(url, headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $jwt"});
  print(response.body);
  return List<User>.from(
      json.decode(response.body).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));
}
```

My model :

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<User> userFromJson(String str) => List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));

String userToJson(List<User> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class User {
    User({
        this.indexNo,
        this.name,
        this.idNumber,
        this.passportNumber,
        this.birthCertNo,
    });

    String indexNo;
    String name;
    int idNumber;
    int passportNumber;
    int birthCertNo;

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
      indexNo: json["IndexNo"],
      name: json["Name"],
      idNumber: json["IdNumber"],
      passportNumber: json["PassportNumber"],
      birthCertNo: json["BirthCertNo"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      "indexNo": indexNo,
      "Name": name,
      "IdNumber": idNumber,
      "PassportNumber": passportNumber,
      "BirthCertNo": birthCertNo,
    };

}
```

My problem is, that although the getUser()seems to return valid data, the statement snapshot.hasdata inside the FutureBuilder widget alsways is false.

What goes wrong here?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Thanks, i got one of your answers working

Comment: Most welcome @tharnos_nos can you tell me which answer is useful to you and please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

try

return List.from(
json.decode(response.body).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)).toList());